# how to configure ViewResolver for concrete controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, configuration

I have spring mvc application. I have 2 controllers -

first uses standart view resolver and render to jsp

second uses resolver for creatin RestFull wev service

How I can configure it?

**UPDATE**

first controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllerPath")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/sayHello")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name", "Vasya");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

it uses

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I need to add one more controller which will work as restful webservice and return json to client

Comment: Can you show some code examples?  You shouldn't need to change the ViewResolver in order to have a RESTful web service.

Comment: topic has been updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do a RESTful handler by simply having the Jackson libraries in your classpath and returning the object you want to serialize to JSON, or by using the `@ResponseBody` annotation to indicate that your returned object should be used as the "body" of the HTTP response directly.

**Using Jackson**

```
@RequestMapping("/myRestful")
MyDomainObject myRestfulService() {
   // .. do some stuff... //
   return new MyDomainObject(); // <- Return some object
}
```

**Using `@ResponseBody`:**

```
@RequestMapping("/myRestful")
@ResponseBody String myRestfulService() {
   // .. do some stuff... //
   return new "This is some string that will be returned, as-is, to the client"; // <- Return some data
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I see The **resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.** in my browser

Comment: i want to see xml or json

Comment: The first example does output JSON.  It uses the Jackson libs to do so.  The second example you can output anything your heart desires, as you are simply telling Spring to take whatever you output as the body of the response.

Comment: The error message you are seeing is because your requesting a different MIME type than what the server is sending.  You can set the MIME type on the HttpServletResponse, which you can include as a parameter of your handler method.